# Button event in Fragment Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am pretty new with Android and I am learning it by reading a Deitel book. I decided to develop an app with tabs and I am using Fragments (as you can see).

I read on my book/on the internet how to implement an `onClick` event for a button, but when I try to run the app in my Android phone, it crashes.

**Code**

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

             EditText val1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
             EditText val2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
             EditText val3 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText3);

             EditText sol1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
             EditText sol2 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText5);

             //Solve the equation using a method of a class I created
             equazioni2grado Equazione = new equazioni2grado();
             Equazione.solveEquation(val1.getText().toString(), val2.getText().toString(), val3.getText().toString());

             //Show the results
             sol1.setText( Equazione.getSol1AsFraction() );
             sol2.setText( Equazione.getSol1AsFraction() );
          }

        }); 

        return view;

    }  

}
```

**XML**
[link](http://pastebin.com/0H5XzntL)

I put the XML in a pastebin because it's pretty long. The XML looks like this:

[image]

I read that I can define the `onClick` event in the XML or in the java file, both ways are possible. I am doing it programmatically as you can see.

I can't find where is my mistake. Any idea?

**Note**: The object Equazione has the method that is:
  `public void solveEquation(String x, String y, String z) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText val1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Use view instead of v as below

```
EditText val1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Answer (score 1):

try the code below:

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        EditText val1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText val2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText val3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        EditText sol1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        EditText sol2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText5);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Solve the equation using a method of a class I created
                equazioni2grado Equazione = new equazioni2grado();
                Equazione.solveEquation(val1.getText().toString(), val2.getText().toString(), val3.getText().toString());

                //Show the results
                sol1.setText( Equazione.getSol1AsFraction() );
                sol2.setText( Equazione.getSol1AsFraction() );
            }
        }); 

        return view;
    }  
}
```

And can you paste LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call findViewById on the view that represents the layout you've inflated. In this case, it's the object "view", returned from inflater.inflate().

One way of doing that is declaring view as a final variable and then replacing the calls "v.findViewById..." with "view.findViewById...".